# insert json into mysql table in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, express

I've table users with following field

id,name(varchar) ,gallery(json)

`gallery` contains the the image path of user uploaded rows, a user can more images to his gallery and the image path of each image is stored in `gallery` as json

here is a sample row

```
id name gallery

1  blob ["test.jpg","test1.jpeg"]
```

Here is my code

```
function(req,res){
//image path after upload
var imagePath =uploadS3();

//SELECT gallery FROM user   and store to oldGallery
 var oldGallery = getCurrentGallery()
 var updatedGallery;
if(oldGallery==null){
    updatedGallery = "[\""+imagePath+"\"]"

}else{
    //concatinate the gallery row with new imagepath
      updatedGallery = JSON.parse(oldGallery).push(imagePath);
 }

   db.query("UPDATE users SET gallery=? ",[updatedGallery],function(error,result){
});
}
```

But the problem with `JSON.parse(oldGallery).push(imagePath);` it didn't worked 
console.log(`JSON.parse(oldGallery).push(imagePath)`) outputs `2` instead of the array.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns length of the array after pushing (not the array itself). You can concatenate it to new array instead:

```
updatedGallery = JSON.parse(oldGallery).concat([imagePath]);
```

Furthermore, the type of `updatedGallery` in your `if` clause is a `String` and in the `else` clause it will be an `Array`. You should make it consistent and use either strings or arrays.

Comment: yeah it close to answer it outputs `[ 'gallery-image-1494059004453.jpeg',
  'gallery-image-1494061668890.jpeg' ]` but i want replace the single quotes with double

Comment: @Jabaa quotes in javascript objects are irrelevant. If it matters to you, convert it to string: `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(oldGallery).concat([imagePath]))`

Comment: Now i will get the string as but i got error in mysql query